# How to keep bots and spiders from consuming my server's resources?

Tags: .htaccess, web-crawler, bots

My PHP script counts unique visitors. The count compared to Google Analytics was absurd; 30 000 a day but Analytics counts 2000. 2000 is the correct number, so I added a condition to my script to avoid counting bots and spiders.

I also made it identify the bots; in little more than 1 minute I had over a 100. Memory is limited and bots are consuming resources, I want to avoid this. My robots.txt :

```
# Allow Google, Yahoo and Bing to crawl all beside of /admin/
User-agent: Googlebot 
User-agent: Yahoo! Slurp
User-agent: msnbot 
Disallow: /admin/ 
Disallow: /analitics/
Disallow: /class/
Allow: / 

# Disallow all other to crawl everywhere
User-agent: * 
Disallow: /
```

Is there a way to prevent this many requests? I don't mind the crawler of Google or Bing, but this is ridiculous. A sample :

```
es ip:40.77.167.161 pais:United States cidade:Boydton user agent:mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)
es ip:40.77.167.87 pais:United States cidade:Boydton user agent:mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)
es ip:40.77.167.87 pais:United States cidade:Boydton user agent:mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)
es ip:40.77.167.87 pais:United States cidade:Boydton user agent:mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)
es ip:40.77.167.87 pais:United States cidade:Boydton user agent:mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)
es ip:40.77.167.87 pais:United States cidade:Boydton user agent:mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)
es ip:40.77.167.87 pais:United States cidade:Boydton user agent:mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)
es ip:40.77.167.87 pais:United States cidade:Boydton user agent:mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)
es ip:40.77.167.87 pais:United States cidade:Boydton user agent:mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)
es ip:40.77.167.87 pais:United States cidade:Boydton user agent:mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)
pt ip:40.77.167.178 pais:United States cidade:Boydton user agent:mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)
pt ip:40.77.167.178 pais:United States cidade:Boydton user agent:mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)
pt ip:40.77.167.178 pais:United States cidade:Boydton user agent:mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)
es ip:40.77.167.87 pais:United States cidade:Boydton user agent:mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)
es ip:40.77.167.87 pais:United States cidade:Boydton user agent:mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)
es ip:40.77.167.140 pais:United States cidade:Boydton user agent:mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)
pt ip:40.77.167.177 pais:United States cidade:Boydton user agent:mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)
pt ip:40.77.167.191 pais:United States cidade:Boydton user agent:mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)
pt ip:40.77.167.178 pais:United States cidade:Boydton user agent:mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)
es ip:40.77.167.87 pais:United States cidade:Boydton user agent:mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because migrate to serverfault

Comment: Something like [cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/lp/overview-a/?_bt=261571487691&_bk=%2Bcloudflare&_bm=b&_bn=g&gclid=Cj0KCQjw1NzZBRCoARIsAIaMwuuGAflKLNTzPpFBmHAREPrHMU8Qmfyw4UY9zst07I2udW_B1zfR3LIaAn4qEALw_wcB) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

First, we have do distinguish between bots that announce correctly and bots who claim to be somebody else. There are a lot of bots who act as other bots for various reasons (not only bad ones). Among the group of bots who announce as somebody else there is a subgroup that also ignores `robots.txt`.

In your case, we seem to have an actual bot from Microsoft.

### Bots obeying robots.txt

The IPs in fact seems to be correct IP addresses from Bing. Microsoft explains that to find out [whether an IP address actually belongs to them](https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/how-to-verify-bingbot-3905dc26), we should use `nslookup`.

This gives us:

```
$ nslookup 40.77.167.87
87.167.77.40.in-addr.arpa   name = msnbot-40-77-167-87.search.msn.com.

$ nslookup msnbot-40-77-167-87.search.msn.com
[...]
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   msnbot-40-77-167-87.search.msn.com
Address: 40.77.167.87
```

Microsoft does not provide a clear example for which name their [bot will listen to in the `robots.txt` file](https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/how-to-create-a-robots-txt-file-cb7c31ec), but I think that they want to see `bingbot` and not `msnbot`.

> Note
>
> **Bingbot**, upon finding a specific set of instructions for itself, will ignore the directives listed in the generic section, so you will need to repeat all of the general directives in addition to the specific directives you created for them in their own section of the file.
>
> [...]
>
> 1. Bots are **referenced as user-agents** in the robots.txt file. [...]
>
> (highlighting by me)

On the other hand, Microsoft links to the [Robots Database](http://www.robotstxt.org/db.html) for a list of valid robot names which does not list Bingbot at all (only msnbot, which you already use).

Still, I would try to add `bingbot` to your user-agents in the `robots.txt` file and see if that helps.

You did not include the actual path requested on each request. There seem to be situations [where Microsoft's Bingbot cannot be blocked with robots.txt](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/44257/bingbot-request-for-trafficbasedsspsitemap-xml-which-does-not-exist#answer-44339).

### Bots not obeying robots.txt

For bots who do not obey robots.txt, you can only use server side detection. You could either block them based on their IP (if you see the requests coming from the same IP all the time) or on their user-agent (if they announce as the same user-agent all the time).

E.g. some websites block the user-agent `scrapy` on the server-side (and return an empty page or 404 or similar), because this is the default used by a popular web scraping framework.

You can also implement the IP based blocking automatically, e.g. if you see more than k requests over x hours, then you block that IP for the next 10*x hours. This can lead to false positives of course if the IP belongs to a consumer ISP, because they often give the same IP address to different users. This means, you might be blocking normal users. However, if you have 2000 visitors per day, I assume the risk that two visitors of your website have the same IP address and that got blocked due to too many requests is low.